# error while insert column in postgresql using shell script?

Tags: postgresql, shell, unix, amazon-ec2, amazon-redshift

Below is my shell script, I am trying to insert columns in posrgresql using shell script.
But getting below error.
**Script:**

```
i='dcm_account494401_click_2017050511_20170505_093843_556195422.csv.gz'
    load_date='2017-05-12'
    load_status='Fail'
    message="INFO:  Load into table 'stg_ft_raw_activity' completed, 362554 record(s) loaded successfully.
    INFO:  Load into table 'stg_ft_raw_activity' completed, 1 record(s) were loaded with replacements made for ACCEPTINVCHARS. Check 'stl_replacements' system table for details.
    "
    psql "host=$HOST  port=$DBPORT dbname=$DBNAME user=$DBUSER password=$DBPASS" -F  --no-align    <<EOF
    truncate table  stg.notification_table;
    \set fname $i

\set load_date $load_date
\set load_status $load_status
\set message $message

insert into  stg.notification_table values (:'fname', :'load_date', :'load_status',:"message");
    EOF
```

error:

```
Expanded display is used automatically.
TRUNCATE TABLE and COMMIT TRANSACTION
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "INFO"
LINE 1: INFO:  Load into table 'stg_ft_raw_activity' completed, 1 re...
    ^
```

message col is string value and also contains spl chars. is that a reason?

Please help to resolve.
Thansk,

Comment: Are you actually using Postgresql, or Redshift? They are related, but have many differences.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use these variables with `\set`.

Here is an example:

```
message="INFO:  Load into table 'stg_ft_raw_activity' completed, 362554 record(s) loaded successfully.
INFO:  Load into table 'stg_ft_raw_activity' completed, 1 record(s) were loaded with replacements made for ACCEPTINVCHARS. Check 'stl_replacements' system table for details.
"

psql <<EOF
INSERT INTO message_table VALUES (\$\$$message\$\$);
EOF
```

This makes use of “[dollar quoting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING)” for string literals, with the `$` signs that are *no* shell variable reference escaped with backslashes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply laurenz. yes  your correct if we use vmessage variable and put the string we can use dollar quoting. but same message if iam getting from log file means i should use /set right.
for example: /set message `cat log.txt `
the same error i am getting here too. How can resolve that.Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: I don't understand. Can you explain that in more detail? Why do you need `\set`?

Comment: echo -e   "No new DCM files for today $logdate">> $psql_fail_log.log
status="No File Found"
duplicate_flag=0
psql "host=$HOST  port=$DBPORT dbname=$DBNAME user=$DBUSER password=$DBPASS" -F  --no-align    <<EOF
\set fname $i
\set load_date $load_date
\set load_status $status
\set is_duplicate $duplicate_flag
 message `cat "$psql_fail_log.log"`

insert into  stg.notification_table values (:'fname', :'load_date', :'load_status',\$\$$message\$\$, :'is_duplicate');
EOF

Comment: Expanded display is used automatically.
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "message"
LINE 1: message No new DCM files for today 17-05-17

Comment: When i run the above  script after  guidance  i am getting the syntax error (above command)

Comment: Don't use any of the `\set` commands, it just makes things more complicated. Don't use something like `:'variable'` either, it is a syntax error. Treat all your parameters like I showed you in the answer.